# Are UK Landing Cards handed to passengers on WizzAir flights arriving at London Luton?

Tags: air-travel, uk, borders, wizz-air, customs-and-immigration

I cannot find any information anywhere on whether WizzAir hands out landing cards to passengers during the flights that land at Luton.

I understand that Landing Cards [have been planned to be scrapped](https://www.standard.co.uk/news/uk/landing-cards-for-noneu-travellers-to-be-scrapped-a3604716.html) during this autumn. **GOV.UK**, however, still states the following: "*Your carrier will give you a landing card - fill this in before you arrive at border control.*" [[source](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/at-border-control)] Therefore, I am assuming they are still in use (also few people who have traveled to the UK very recently have confirmed this, but they all flew either into Gatwick or Heathrow).

London Luton's website mentions **nothing** about Landing Cards. (london-luton.co.uk/inside-lla/passport-control)

***QUESTIONS***

- Does WizzAir hand out landing cards? What if they don't?
- Are landing cards even required at London Luton Aiport?

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: I've never encountered an airport where required forms weren't available somewhere in the immigration area for those who didn't complete them on the plane, so the worst case scenario is that you fill it out there.

Comment: Landing cards will be available after you land if they are not on the plane.

Answer (score 6):

Landing cards are required for non EU travellers at Luton, just as at every other UK airport. Many budget carriers within the EU no longer hand out landing cards on the flight (this may include Wizz Air, Ryanair certainly don't), probably because the overwhelming majority of passengers don't need them. At Luton, and as far as I know, every other international airport in the UK, landing cards are available at the border. Luton has an area with pencils available for you to fill them out.

Comment: EasyJet's policy seems to be 1) Put out an announcement similar to "Landing Cards are required for non-EU passengers at <x> airport. If you require a landing card, please ask a member of crew for one" 2) A member of crew then walks down the aisle offering them to passengers.

As the EU Advanced Passenger Name record requires the passport details, the airline is likely to know (if the passenger is on a return flight), which passport everyone is flying on.